# Prevent UIScrollView from going up further than the starting position

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

UIScrollViews have that default iOS behavior where a user can scroll up past the start of the screen and the whole screen bounces to indicate they can't go up any further. After they release, it just brings them back down in a bouncy way to the original content offset of 0.

Is there a way I can remove that native functionality? I basically only want them to scroll down (and only back up if the content offset is > 0).

I know how to hook into the scrolling event to say content offset <= 0 then content offset = 0, but that still lets them drag and it only changes it after they let go. I literally don't want the scrollview to go up <= 0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the bounce.

In your storyboard in the Attributes inspector by unchecking these 3 boxes:

[image]

Or programmatically:

```
yourScrollView.bounces=false
yourScrollView.alwaysBounceVertical=false
yourScrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal=false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to bounce bottom but not top you can implement an delegate on scrollview and use the following function:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0 {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero
    }
}
```